# What are the various legal roles along the line of POA

Tags: power-of-attorney, south-carolina

I've heard legal speak of executor, agent, power of attorney, guardian.  I don't understand the differences.  Are these legal terms?  how/where are they defined?  Are their other terms for the same or other roles in the situation of an elderly person ?